# What does classname.class refer to in Android?

Tags: java, android

For example, when we create an intent, we use

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LoginActivity.class);
```

What does `.class` refer to? Is it the name of the class as a string? Or is it the class itself? Why can't I just pass`LoginActivity` instead of `LoginActivity.class`?

Answer (score 4):

It refers to an instance of the `Class` object itself. See the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for `Class`. In this case, the `Intent` [constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) takes an instance of the `Activity` which you want to start. This is also called an explicit `Intent` because you are explicitly defining the component you wish to start, whereas an implicit `Intent` is resolved at runtime by Android.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the applicable constructor, [`public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29), documentation, you will notice that the second parameter requires a class object. The way to provide the class for any object is to do `object.getClass()` or `<className>.class`.

Answer (score 1):

```
ClassName.class
```

refers to the destination activity to which you want to open from the current acitivity. 
its like a hiperlink in html `<a href="contactus.html">contact</a>` when you click on the contact link contactus.html page will be opened.